# Produces class dependency list in python

Tags: python

I am trying to implement a python program that analyzes python source files in a given directory
and produces class dependency list, along with the source filename in which the
class definition is found, in the following format.

```
Class name1 [filename]
 Derived Classname1 [filename]
 Derived Classname2 [filename]
 Derived Classname3 [filename]
 …
 Class name2 [filename]
 Derived ClassnameA [filename]
 Derived ClassnameB[filename]
 Derived ClassnameC [filename]
```

I could not figure out the logic.
Code to read the files from directory is given below
is there a module for inheritance logic in python?
cmd command: >>python cs2.py "C:\Users\PC-server\Documents\PythonCode\dir1"

cs2.py

```
import sys
import os
def processFiles(path):
    try: 
        fileList = os.listdir(path)
        for i in fileList:
            filePath= path +"\\"+i;
            if(os.path.isfile(filePath)):
                fileName = i;
                print(filePath)
                file = open(filePath, 'r')
                #logic will go here
            #file.close()
    except: 
        print('Error reading the directory')
def main(argv):
   processFiles(argv)
main(sys.argv[1])
```

Comment: are you looking to get all python files in a dir ??

Comment: and if you want to know the base classes of a class what you need to do is ast parsing. https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html

Comment: If you want to do it without a module, you can always read the file, check for lines which begin with the `class` keyword (after stripping whitespace, of course), and then parse those.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So after a lot of researching and after spending two days on this I am able to achieve the desired result by breaking the problems in parts and combining chunk of code from various stack over flow questions

I have just starting learning python and obviously the code could be written more efficiently. But at present I am happy with the result.

```
#python cs2.py "C:\Users\PC-server\Documents\PythonCode\testClasses"
import sys
import os
import ast  
import inspect

def importClasses(path,fileList):
    sys.path.append(path)    
    for i in fileList:
        filePath= path +"\\"+i;
        if(os.path.isfile(filePath)):
            fileName = i
            name, ext = os.path.splitext(fileName)
            module = __import__(name)
            globals()[name] = module
            
def printSubClassResult(className):
    subclasses = eval(className).__subclasses__()
    for cls in subclasses:
        classFileName = os.path.basename(inspect.getmodule(cls).__file__)
        print("\t",cls.__name__, "[", classFileName, "]")    

def printClassResult(path,fileList):
    for i in fileList:
            filePath= path +"\\"+i;
            if(os.path.isfile(filePath)):
                fileName = i
                name, ext = os.path.splitext(fileName)
                file = open(filePath, "r")
                code = file.read()
                tree = ast.parse(code)
                classes = [node for node in ast.walk(tree) if isinstance(node, ast.ClassDef)]
                for classObj in classes:
                    print(classObj.name, "[", fileName, "]")
                    className = name + "."+ classObj.name
                    printSubClassResult(className)
                    print("\n")
                    
def processFiles(path):
    
    try:
        fileList = os.listdir(path)
        
        importClasses(path,fileList)
        
        printClassResult(path,fileList)
        
    except BaseException as err:
        print(f"Unexpected {err=}, {type(err)=}")
    
def main(argv):
   processFiles(argv)
   
main(sys.argv[1])
```